# What is the option I have to choose to close a topic when the question asked is fundamentally wrong?

Tags: discussion

[Related](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/how-do-we-handle-it-when-the-askers-problem-is-just-that-theyre-confused), maybe even duplicated, but it really did not seem to address my question/problem.

Let say that I found a [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93989/what-ways-are-there-of-reliably-getting-attacks-in-others-turns?noredirect=1#comment217134_93989) that is based on a fundamental mistake (e.g. a misunderstanding of a rule, in this case how many actions he can do with the ready action in DnD-5e). The first thing to do is to give a comment to the OP that his question is based on a mistake. The problem is that is highly probable that if the mistake is fixed the question is not longer relevant or be substantially different. In that case it should be voted to close or, at least, flag it (but wouldn't flagging it be redundant?). The thing is, the options given to vote to close are:

- Duplicate question
- Off-topic (with sub-reasons)
- Unclear what you're asking
- Too broad
- Primarily opinion-based

It is not a duplicated question, nor an Off-topic, unclear (it is clear what he is asking, just fundamentally wrong), too broad and opinion based. Which one should I have to choose, *if any*? As the related meta question stated, the problem is not the question itself, but the foundation of the question.

Comment: You're absolutely right that this is a duplicate of the question about folks who are confused, and the proper response is to either [put it on hold as unclear](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3507/4398) or give the asker a full answer [as described in point #3](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3509/4398), depending on the severity and depth of the confusion.

Comment: @BESW I'm very aware of that question (thus my opening statement), point 3 seems to be close to answer to what I asked and the "put it on hold as unclear" is supporting it. But the reason I wrote the question is because I was confused on what option to take (on the vote system) on a "blatantly wrong" that is very clear what he is asking. I think is different because I knew what I wanted to do (vote it to close) just that the options weren't clear... and *unclear* does not seem to hold, thus my confusion.

Comment: Funny enough, SevenSidedDie once told me on a comment that a question with the same answer not necessarily is a duplicated question. So, it may hold the question (as reference maybe). Am I wrong in this particular case and it really is duplicated?

Comment: @Chepelink It's a judgement call thing sometimes. On Meta we might do things a bit differently to point people toward existing policy discussion in ways we wouldn't ordinarily on main site. In this case, 3 other people or a diamond moderator would also have to agree with that judgement, and users may in turn disagree and reopen this question.

Comment: @doppelgreener I understand. Just to be clear and to close this discussion and question. **In Meta**, even if the questions is somehow different (From "how do I handle a confused player?" to "I want to close the question for being wrong, what vote option should I choose?"), since the solution in the first post kind of solves the question, it holds as duplicate and I should hit the "That solved my problem!" button that in the post right now. Right?

Comment: @Chepelink If you feel it does solve your issue (maybe with the confirmation and advice BESW provided), you may hit that button and it will close this question as a duplicate of that one. If you feel that it didn't solve it, or you otherwise don't agree with this being a duplicate, you are OK to *not* hit that button, and also OK to do nothing (as opposed to the "I'll edit this to show how it's different" prompt). It won't cause trouble and we won't hold it against you, our primary concern is ensuring you understand what to do. (In fact I think I should revise my answer on that possible dupe.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/how-do-we-handle-a-desire-to-challenge-the-frame-of-a-question